# Unable to activate chef-provisioning-docker-0.6 because chef-provisioning-1.1.1 conflicts with chef-provisioning (~> 0.9)

Tags: docker, vagrant, chef-infra

I have the following code in my `Vagrantfile`

```
  config.vm.provision "chef_zero" do |chef|
    chef.add_recipe 'docker'
    chef.add_recipe 'chef-provisioning'
    chef.add_recipe 'chef-provisioning::docker'
```

This fails with a recipe compile error `Gem::ConflictError`. Console shows

```
==> default: Gem::ConflictError
==> default: ------------------
==> default: Unable to activate chef-provisioning-docker-0.6, because chef-provisioning-1.1.1 conflicts with chef-provisioning (~> 0.9)
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: Cookbook Trace:
==> default: ---------------
==> default:   /tmp/vagrant-chef/1f9b550042b33ab1889a3ac9e3f61960/cookbooks/chef-provisioning/recipes/docker.rb:25:in `from_file'
==> default: 
==> default: Relevant File Content:
==> default: ----------------------
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-chef/1f9b550042b33ab1889a3ac9e3f61960/cookbooks/chef-provisioning/recipes/docker.rb:
==> default: 
==> default:  18:  #
==> default:  19:  include_recipe 'chef-provisioning::default'
==> default:  20:  
==> default:  21:  chef_gem 'chef-provisioning-docker' do
==> default:  22:    version node['chef-provisioning']['docker']['version']
==> default:  23:  end
==> default:  24:  
==> default: 
==> default:  25>> require 'chef/provisioning/docker_driver/driver'
```

Answer (score 0):

Newer ChefDK versions are incompatible with the `chef-provisioning-docker` gem. There is an [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/chef/chef-provisioning-docker/issues/47) regarding this and they're [working on compatibility](https://github.com/chef/chef-provisioning-docker/pull/47)

`chef-dk-0.6.0 depends on chef-provisioning (~> 1.1.1)
chef-provisioning-docker-0.6 depends on chef-provisioning (~> 0.9)`